# How to pass a variable in a URL using Perl?

Tags: perl, url, variables, foreach

I'm trying to pass parameters in a URL. I don't know what's missing, I tried to see how the URL looks after executing this script.

```
my $request3 = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $sql_activation);

my $useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$useragent->timeout(10);

my $response2 = $useragent->request($request3);
if ($response2->is_success) {

    my $res2 = $response2->content;

    if ($res =~ m/[#](.*):(.*)[#]/g) {
        my ($key, $username) = ($1, $2);
        print "[+] $username:$key \n\n";
    }
    else {
      print "[-] Error \n\n";
    }
}

my $link =
      "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=" 
    . $key
    . "&login="
    . $username;

sub post_url {

    my ($link, $formref) = @_;

    my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(timeout => 300);
    $ua->agent('perlproc/1.0');
    my $get = $ua->post($link, $formref);

    if ($get->is_success) {
        print "worked \n";
    }
    else {
        print "Failed \n";
    }
}
```

After executing the script the URL is like this

```
site/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=&login=
```

Comment: What do you expect `$key` and `$username` to be? Can you show where they are set?

Comment: What's missing is any code to set the variables you are using to construct the URI.

Comment: (And mashing strings together to make URIs isn't a great idea, use the  [URI module](https://metacpan.org/module/GAAS/URI-1.60/URI.pm).)

Comment: @gpojd i've edited the code above

Comment: Adding `use strict` to your code would have given you a big clue to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl has block level scope. You define `$key` and `$username` in the block following an `if` statement. They don't live beyond that.

You need to create them (with `my`) *before* that block.

```
# HERE
my ( $key, $username );
if ( $response2->is_success ) {
    my $res2 = $response2->content;
    if ( $res =~ m/[#](.*):(.*)[#]/g ) {
        # Don't say my again
        ( $key, $username ) = ( $1, $2 );
    }
    else { print "[-] Error \n\n"; }
}
```

Comment: @gilardinho, I'd go a step further and add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the top of your script. It would have caught that bug for you.